# Find the difference in table1 number of rows between sources S1 and S2 and update table2

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

**TABLE1**

```
call_ID PARAM_CT status
------- -------- -------------    
C001     3         NULL
```

**TABLE2**

```
+---------+---------+----------+----------+------------------+---------+    
| seq_ID  | REQ_ID  | CALL_ID  | SELL_ID  |     REGION       |  NUMBER|    
+---------+---------+----------+----------+------------------+---------+    
|    1    |    123  | C001     | S1       | ABC              |  510563 |    
|    2    |    123  | C001     | S1       | EFG              |  122967 |    
|    3    |    123  | C001     | S1       | HIJ              |  614106 |    
|    4    |    123  | C001     | S2       | ABC              |  510563 |    
|    5    |    123  | C001     | S2       | ERG              |  122967 |    
|    6    |    123  | C001     | S2       | HIJ              |  614106 |
+---------+---------+----------+----------+------------------+---------+
```

Below is the code that i am using to find the difference in number of rows between sources S1 and S2. Please let me know if this can be optimized.

```
DECLARE vPARAM_CT VARCHAR(10) ;
DECLARE vSOURCE1 VARCHAR(10) ;
DECLARE vSOURCE2 VARCHAR(10) ;
BEGIN
SELECT PARAM_CT into vPARAM_CT FROM table1 WHERE call_id='C001' ;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO vSOURCE1 FROM table2 WHERE call_id='C001' AND SOURCE='S1';
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO vSOURCE2 FROM table2 WHERE call_id='C001' AND SOURCE='S2'; 
IF (vPARAM_CT=vSOURCE1 AND vSOURCE2=vPARAM_CT ) THEN
BEGIN
  UPDATE table1 SET RUN_STATUS='COMPLETED' WHERE call_id='C001' ;
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
UPDATE table1 SET RUN_STATUS='COMPLETE WITH MISSING COUNTRY CODE' WHERE call_id='C001'  ;
END;
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: What is your expected result? And why are the variables declared as `VARCHAR` if they seem to store integers?

Comment: That code won't compile also; you need just one `declare` clause, then your variables.  And you have a lot of unnecessary begin and end blocks too.

Comment: The answer code is perfect for the requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to write `declare` only once for a PLSQL code block, and return the 
results for `count` aggregation to a numeric type parameter.

Then, combine your `select` statements into one and for `if` blocks as below :

```
DECLARE 
   v_cnt     pls_integer;
   v_call_id varchar2(10) := 'C001';
BEGIN

 select count(*) 
   into v_cnt
   from
     ( select call_id,
              sum(case when source = 'S1' then 1 else 0 end ) as s1,
              sum(case when source = 'S2' then 1 else 0 end ) as s2
         from table2
        group by call_id 
     ) t2
         join table1 t1 on t1.param_ct = t2.s1 and t1.param_ct = t2.s2
        where call_id = 'C001';

  IF ( v_cnt > 0 ) THEN
    UPDATE table1 SET RUN_STATUS='COMPLETED' WHERE call_id=v_call_id ;
  ELSE
    UPDATE table1 SET RUN_STATUS='COMPLETED WITH MISSING COUNTRY CODE' WHERE call_id=v_call_id  ;
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Perfect for my requirement here. Thank you :-)